# Can I implement Eq for a type which can contain a list of itself?

Tags: idris

This code doesn't compile:

```
data Foo = A String | B (List Foo)

Eq Foo where
  (==) (A x) (A y) = x == y
  (==) (B xs) (B ys) = xs == ys
  (==) _ _ = False
```

It yields the following error:

> Type checking ./eq.idr eq.idr:11:3-27:    | 11 |   (==) (A x) (A y) =
>   x == y    |   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Prelude.Interfaces.Main.Foo
>   implementation of Prelude.Interfaces.Eq, method == is possibly not
>   total due to recursive path Prelude.Interfaces.Main.Foo implementation
>   of Prelude.Interfaces.Eq, method == --> Prelude.Interfaces.Main.Foo
>   implementation of Prelude.Interfaces.Eq, method ==

So is the problem here that we're relying on `Eq Foo` in its implementation, hence the recursive path? That doesn't seem to explain it, because this compiles:

```
data Bar = C String | D Bar

Eq Bar where
  (==) (C x) (C y) = x == y
  (==) (D x) (D y) = x == y
  (==) _ _ = False
```

So - I can have recursive calls to `==` on whatever I'm defining the implementation on, but I can't to lists of it? Am I missing a trick to make this work, or am I trying to do something that's fundamentally broken somewhere?

Comment: Perhaps you can look into [`WellFounded`](https://www.idris-lang.org/docs/1.0/prelude_doc/docs/Prelude.WellFounded.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function that decides equality needs to be implemented in terms of mutual recursion, just as `Foo` itself is defined by mutual recursion.

```
Eq Foo where
  (==) = eq
    where mutual -- massive indentation necessary
            eq : Foo -> Foo -> Bool
            eq (A l) (A r) = l == r
            eq (B l) (B r) = eq1 l r
            eq _ _ = False 
            eq1 : List Foo -> List Foo -> Bool
            eq1 (l :: ls) (r :: rs) = eq l r && eq1 ls rs
            eq1 [] [] = True
            eq1 _ _ = False
```

You can't reuse `List`'s own `(==)`, but it is possible to factor out a pattern.

```
zipWithFoldrElem : (ls : List a) -> (rs : List a) -> ((l : a) -> (r : a) -> Elem (l, r) (zip ls rs) -> b) -> (b -> Lazy b -> b) -> b -> b -> b -> b
zipWithFoldrElem [] [] _ _ e _ _ = e
zipWithFoldrElem [] (_ :: _) _ _ _ el _ = el
zipWithFoldrElem (_ :: _) [] _ _ _ _ er = er
zipWithFoldrElem (l :: ls) (r :: rs) f g e el er = f l r Here `g` zipWithFoldLazyElem ls rs (\l, r, e => f l r (There e)) g e el er

Eq Foo where
  (A l) == (A r) = l == r
  (B l) == (B r) = zipWithFoldrElem l r (f l r) (&&) True False False
   where f : (ls : List Foo) -> (rs : List Foo) -> (l : Foo) -> (r : Foo) -> Elem (l, r) (zip ls rs) -> Bool
         f (l :: _) (r :: _) l r Here = l == r
         f (_ :: ls) (_ :: rs) l r (There e) = f ls rs l r e
         f [] [] _ _ _ impossible
  _ == _ = False
```

And, for show, here's a lexicographic `Ord`:

```
Ord Foo where
  compare (A l) (A r) = l `compare` r
  compare (B l) (B r) = zipWithFoldrElem l r (f l r) thenCompare EQ LT GT
    where f : (ls : List Foo) -> (rs : List Foo) -> (l : Foo) -> (r : Foo) -> Elem (l, r) (zip ls rs) -> Ordering
          f (l :: _) (r :: _) l r Here = l `compare` r
          f (_ :: ls) (_ :: rs) l r (There e) = f ls rs l r e
          f [] [] _ _ _ impossible
  compare (A _) (B _) = LT
  compare (B _) (A _) = GT
```

Comment: Thanks! It's the requirement for _mutually_ recursive functions which wasn't obvious to me - still getting used to working with totality.

Comment: @TomJohnson If you look at how `Foo` is structured, you see: `Foo = A String | B (List Foo); List Foo = (::) Foo (List Foo) | Nil`, where `Foo` never directly recurses to itself, only to `List Foo`, and `List Foo` both recurses to itself and to `Foo`. Similarly, many functions that go through a `Foo` will have the structure of two mutually recursive parts where one calls into the other and not itself and the other calls both itself and the first one.

Comment: Yep, it makes sense now you raise it. The step here was just realising that mutual recursion is an important concept in totality checking: it's not something I was looking for before.

Answer (score 0):

There's a much nicer way, now that I've grokked `WellFounded` a bit.

This data type is to `Foo` as `Elem` is to `List`. It tells you where to find a sub-`Foo` in a `Foo`.

```
-- s is smaller than b if either ...
data Smaller : (s : Foo) -> (b : Foo) -> Type where
  -- it is one of the elements of ss when b = B ss
  Surface : Elem s ss -> Smaller s (B ss)
  -- it is smaller than one of the elements of ms when b = B ms
  -- "m" is for "medium"
  Deeper  : Smaller s m -> Elem m ms -> Smaller s (B ms)
```

`Smaller` is `WellFounded`:

```
WellFounded Smaller where
  wellFounded x = Access (acc x)
    where mutual
            acc : (b : Foo) -> (s : Foo) -> Smaller s b -> Accessible Smaller s
            acc (B ss) s (Surface e) = accSurface ss s e
            acc (B ms) s (Deeper {m} sr e) = accDeeper ms m e s sr
            accSurface : (ss : List Foo) -> (s : Foo) -> Elem s ss -> Accessible Smaller s
            accSurface (s :: _) s Here = Access (acc s)
            accSurface (_ :: ss) s (There e) = accSurface ss s e
            accDeeper : (ms : List Foo) -> (m : Foo) -> Elem m ms -> (s : Foo) -> Smaller s m -> Accessible Smaller s
            accDeeper (m :: _) m Here s sr = acc m s sr
            accDeeper (_ :: ms) m (There e) s sr = accDeeper ms m e s sr
```

This uses mutual recursion, just like my older answer, but it abstracts it away much more cleanly. The general skeleton of a `WellFounded` instance is:

```
WellFounded (rel : a -> a -> Type) where -- rel s b means s is smaller than b
  wellFounded x = Access (acc x)
    where acc : (b : a) -> (s : a) -> rel s b -> Accessible rel s
    -- Accessible is really cryptic:
    -- Access : (rec : (y : a) -> rel y x -> Accessible rel y) -> Accessible rel x
    -- but the idea of acc is simple:
    -- we convince the totality checker s is really smaller than b
    -- acc needs to be recursive, and when it convinces the totality
    -- checker, it can end with Access (acc s)
```

`WellFounded` buys us

```
wfRec : WellFounded rel =>
        (step : (x : a) ->
                (rec : (y : a) -> rel y x -> b) ->
                b
        ) ->
        a -> b
```

`step` is a function defined by open recursion. `step` gets an argument `rec`, and, instead of recursing to itself, `step` calls `rec` with a proof that the argument it's recursing on is the right size, and `wfRec` routes the call back to `step` (essentially it's `fix : (step : (rec : (a -> b)) -> (x : a) -> b) -> a -> b; fix f x = f (fix f) x` but total.)

We can now, cleanly, factor out the logic of `(==)` on lists:

```
eqBy : (ls : List a) -> (rs : List a) -> ((l : a) -> (r : a) -> (el : Elem l ls) -> (er : Elem r rs) -> Bool) -> Bool
eqBy (l :: ls) (r :: rs) eq = eq l r Here Here && eqBy ls rs (\l, r, el, er => eq l r (There el) (There er))
eqBy [] [] _ = True
eqBy _ _ _ = False
```

And the `Eq` instance is not much worse than the naive one:

```
Eq Foo where
  (==) = wfRec step
    where step : (x : Foo) -> ((y : Foo) -> Smaller y x -> Foo -> Bool) -> Foo -> Bool
          step (A l) _ (A r) = l == r
          step (B l) rec (B r) = eqBy l r (\l, r, el, er => rec l (Surface el) r)
          step _ _ _ = False
```

`eqBy` and the `WellFounded` instance are now much more reusable than the `zipWithFoldrElem` abomination I previously created.